# Add .dtd file in android project for validation XML document

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

How add .dtd file in android project for validation XML document. I file add to resoursce but no work.

```
 XmlDocumentType docType = _indexDoc.CreateDocumentType("DataSet",
 null, "file.dtd", null);
 _indexDoc.AppendChild(docType)
```

ERROR: System.IO.FileNotFoundException has been thrown.
Could not find file /file.dtd".

I work in Xamarin.Android C#

Answer (score 0):

When you create the _indexDoc, ensure that you set XmlResolver to null. This will allow you to create a document type for a file that doesn't exist.

```
XmlDocument _indexDoc=new XmlDocument();
_indexDoc.XmlResolver = null;
XmlDocumentType docType = _indexDoc.CreateDocumentType("DataSet", null, "file.dtd", null);
_indexDoc.AppendChild(docType)
```